# Replace Marker image in React Native Maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have multiple `<Marker>` icons in my `<ClusteringMap>` container. I wanted to change the Marker's `<Image>` on `<Marker> onPress={locationTapped}` action. However, even if I force re-render all marker images onPress, I do not get the changed `<Marker>` image. Here's what I tried

```js
import ClusteringMap from "react-native-map-clustering";
import MapView, { Marker, MapPressEvent, LatLng } from "react-native-maps";
import homeMarkerBlue from "../../../../assets/homeMarkerBlue.png";
import homeMarker from "../../../../assets/homeMarker.png";

//... other imports

const [markerIndex, setMarkerIndex] = useState<number>(0);

const locationTapped = (e: MapPressEvent) => {
  // ...updated Array logic
  setMapData(tempProperty);
  setMarkerIndex(index);
};

const setMarkerIcon = (index: number) => {
  console.log("markerIndex:: ", markerIndex);
  console.log("index:: ", index);
  if (markerIndex === index) {
    // I get the expected result here, but the UI does not update onTap
    return <Image style={styles.markerBlue} source={homeMarkerBlue} />;
  }
  return <Image style={styles.marker} source={homeMarker} />;
};

return (
  <ClusteringMap
    mapRef={mapView}
    coordinates={markers}
    mapStyle={styles.mapContainer}
  >
    {markers.map((item, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        identifier={`${index}`}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: item.latitude,
          longitude: item.longitude,
        }}
        onPress={locationTapped}
      >
        {setMarkerIcon(index)}
      </Marker>
    ))}
  </ClusteringMap>
);
```

Comment: I posted my own answer. Its fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the index and markerIndex type.

```
if (Number(markerIndex) === Number(index)) {
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: you can try it as this   if (markerIndex == index)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add a custom marker to the map.

```
const setMarkerIcon = (index: number) => {
```

console.log('markerIndex:: ', markerIndex);
console.log('index:: ', index);

```
if (markerIndex == index) { // I get the expected result here, but the UI does not update onTap
    return (
      <Image
        style={styles.markerBlue}
        source={homeMarkerBlue}
      />
    )
  }
```

for reference read [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-custom-react-native-map-markers/)

Comment: Yes I tried that by adding a ``require``, but do not get the expected changed icon. Then I tried with importing the png path.

Comment: Please try it. there was issue with require @DeepakThakur

Comment: I tried with the updated ``require`` method. It still doesn't change the marker image ``onPress``

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for some reason, `markerIndex` and `index` have different type, so the `markerIndex === index` comparison return `false`

There are 2 simple solutions:

1. Force 2 variables to same type:

```js
if (Number(markerIndex) === Number(index)) {
```

2. Use loose equality operator:

```js
if (markerIndex == index) {
```